# Accessing normalized form data in a controller in Symofny 2

Tags: forms, symfony

I had to add a form event listener (PRE_SUBMIT) to my FormType in order to set a default value of a field based on the value of another field submitted by the user:

```
//In my FormType:

public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $formData = $event->getData();
    if (empty($formData['time_until'])) {
        $date = new \DateTime($formData['time_from']);
        $date->add(new \DateInterval('PT1H'));
        $formData['time_until'] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
    }
    $event->setData($formData);
}
```

`time_unti` key is set and later its value is mapped onto the form's `time_until` field which is of `datetime` type:

```
        ->add('time_until', datetime, [
            'required' => false,
            'input' => 'datetime',
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm',
            'label' => false,
        ])
```

No problem so far. However, I need to have access to the normalized values of the form fields in my controller, and not `DateTime` objects that are present on the form after the call to `$form->handleRequest($request);`

By "normalized", I mean I want to be able to do:

`$form->get('time_until')` and have a string in the form 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' returned, and not the `DateTime` object stored in the form under `time_until` key.

Advice would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: $form->get('time_until')->format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');

Answer (score 0):

1. you could just add some attribute `$normalizedTimeUntil` in your form type class + add getter `getNormalizedTimeUntil()` that would return this value. Then in Form event you can set this attribute and in controller you can pull it out of form type object with the getter function
2. or you can add non-mapped string form field `timeUntilString` (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped) and fill it in form event
3. or you can add transformer (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) to transform this Datetime object into string. This would be convienent if you for example need to store date in string form in the database). Then form field getter would return string in controller (and would get stored in the db in string also)